# Text extraction from a receipt using OCR API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ruby, ionic-framework

I'm a student hoping to write an app using Rails, and Angularjs with Ionic to create an app so that you can take a picture of a receipt from a restaurant and it extracts the items names, quantity, price and total so that the bill can be split depending on what has been chosen to pay for.

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction of a decent OCR API to use and how I would go about extracting the information I need from it.

I was thinking about scanning for the word total and getting the next number after that but wasn't sure how to get the prices, quantities and names of the items. Any help would be much appreciated it.

Thanks

Comment: using this gem: https://github.com/dannnylo/rtesseract could potentially solve your issue but keep yourself open for other libraries from different languages as well..since this functionality can be added as a microservice.

Comment: Ideally on SO, you should be asking your doubts related to code rather than asking for suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]" and "[help/on-topic]". Asking for recommendations of off-site resources is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You might want to look into [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: tesseract is exactly what im after, thank you